# any((x := word) Invalid Syntax due to :=

Tags: python

What I am trying to achieve is to get the word (from a list) that was found in a string.

After some searching in this awesome community I was able to construct what I needed:

```
tagstoserch= {
               "#WORD": {"First": "asd", "Last": "bcd"},
               "#ANOTHERWORD": {"First": "qwe", "User": "ytr"}
             }
teste = "asdasd asdasd#WORDasdasds#ANOTHERWORD"

if any((x := word) in teste for word in tagstoserch):
    print(tagstoserch[x]["First"])
else:
    print("N/A")
```

This works perfectly on my PC that is running on 3.9 python

But when I try to run on RHEL that as 3.6 it's giving the following error:

```
if any((x := word) in teste for word in tagstoserch):
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is this related to the python version?

Or is another way to do this more elegant? (really need to get one of the words that he finds)

Comment: The `:=` was added in Python 3.8.

Comment: ahahah thank you @Kemp.. is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Do you only need one match? Once you find `#WORD` you don't care about `#ANOTHERWORD`?

Comment: @AlexHall I don't care.. I just need to find one of them and retrieve what word was to then get the "First" or "Last" for that word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for word in tagstoserch:
    if word in teste:
        print(tagstoserch[word]["First"])
        break
else:
    print("N/A")
```

Comment: stupid ahahah this makes sense.. I was just trying to do this in a single row since I have more elif for other situations.. but I get the picture and will try to accommodate this or try to upgrade python =D

Comment: @AlexandreTorres: For a one-liner, try `next(w for w in tagstosearch if w in teste)` (check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) for how to handle the not-found situation).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
[tagstoserch[word]['First'] if word in teste else 'N/A' for word in tagstoserch ]
```

if you need to print you can print using a for loop on this list